# Robot Framework: save SQL results to excel

Tags: excel, robotframework, keyword

I just started to automate our test process. I made the following case:

Example:

*** Settings ***

Library           Selenium2Library

Library           Remote    http://localhost:0000/    WITH NAME   JDBCDB2    #DB2

Library           ExcelLibrary

*** Test Cases ***

Connect to database    connection parm    login    password

Store Query Result To File    select * from table where x=y     :\Testresults.txt

1. what keyword to use (instead of Store query results to file) so i can read the query from a file, instead of writing the full select statement.
2. How to write the sql results to an excel. Results seperated in columns/records

Comment: What is stopping you from importing your _text_ pipe delimited file into Excel, and telling Excel that the pipes are the column separators?

Comment: Can you provide us with an [mcve] of the issue you're facing? Presently I don't know which keyword libraries you're using, how the information is passed from one to the other etc.

Comment: I rephrased my initial question.